# creating array in array from user defined columns of mysql

Tags: php

In the table i have column names as DATE,TIME ,L1,L2,L3,L4 and its corresponding values

```
DATE | TIME    |  L1 | L2 | L3 | L4
------------------------------------------
24Feb|14:00:09|20  | 21 |22   | 23
24Feb|14:01:09|20  | 29 |23   | 24
24Feb|14:02:09|20  | 59 |23   |44
```

I want to create an array of array

which gets all the values under L1,L2,L3,l4 as an  array

and second array under time as one more array.

```
$columns_array  = array(array(L1),array(L2),array(L3),array(L4));

$time = array(t1,t2,t3,t4);
```

Below code  i tried

```
$select_qry  = mysql_query("select * from tab");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_qry))
  {
      $array[] = $row;
  }
 unset($array[0]);
$rt =  array_values($array);
```

Comment: The code you tried has a syntax error on the first line.

Comment: unset to remove the column names from array(0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the table you're pulling from:

```
DATE  | TIME     | L1 | L2 | L3 | L4
------------------------------------------
24Feb | 14:00:09 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23
24Feb | 14:01:09 | 20 | 29 | 23 | 24
24Feb | 14:02:09 | 20 | 59 | 23 | 44
```

You want the values from the fields L1, L2, L3, and l4 inserted into a two dimensional array as you have specified with the following line of code:

```
$columns_array  = array(array(L1),array(L2),array(L3),array(L4));
```

And you want all of the time entries inserted into a time array like this:

```
$time = array(t1,t2,t3,t4);
```

According to your specifications, the two-dimensional array should end up looking like this for this specific sample data table:

```
$columns_array['L1'][0] = 20;
$columns_array['L1'][1] = 20;
$columns_array['L1'][2] = 20;

$columns_array['L2'][0] = 21;
$columns_array['L2'][1] = 29;
$columns_array['L2'][2] = 59;

$columns_array['L3'][0] = 22;
$columns_array['L3'][1] = 23;
$columns_array['L3'][2] = 23;

$columns_array['L4'][0] = 23;
$columns_array['L4'][1] = 24;
$columns_array['L4'][2] = 44;
```

And, of course, the time array should look something like this:

```
$time[0] = 14:00:09;
$time[1] = 14:01:09;
$time[2] = 14:02:09;
```

The following code will do exactly this:

```
$time = array();
$L1_array = array();
$L2_array = array();
$L3_array = array();
$L4_array = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
```

Because we are iterating over each record in the table, the variable $row should
appear in the following format with every pass through the while loop:
$row == array("24Feb", "14:00:09", "20", "21", "22", "23")
meaning, that if I access $row['TIME'] during this first pass, it will give me 14:00:09

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $time[] = $row['TIME'];
    $L1_array[] = $row['L1'];  // first pass will set this to: 20
    $L2_array[] = $row['L2'];  // first pass will set this to: 21
    $L3_array[] = $row['L3'];  // first pass will set this to: 22
    $L4_array[] = $row['L4'];  // first pass will set this to: 23
}
```

By the time this while loop has looped through each of the sample records
each of the L_arrays will look like this:

```
$L1_array == array(20,20,20);
$L2_array == array(21,29,59);
$L3_array == array(22,23,23);
$L4_array == array(23,24,44);
```

Now, all we have left to do is place each of the "L" arrays into the columns_array, and voila.

```
$columns_array = array($L1_array,$L2_array,$L3_array,$L4_array);
```

Comment: This is wrong .I want to create an array of array

which gets all the values under L1,L2,L3,l4 as an array

Comment: I'm sorry, but then you're not explaining yourself well enough. This code will produce exactly this: $columns_array  = array(array(L1),array(L2),array(L3),array(L4)); as you have specified.

Comment: I don't think you understand how php's mysql library works. Unsetting the first row will not remove the column names, you're just removing the first entry that's returned.

Comment: would you mind trying this code - from what you're explaining, this is exactly what you're looking for. Then perhaps you can recall the downvote? :)

Comment: @markrammmy hey, wondering where you're at with this. I see you still haven't removed the downvote. Have you even tried the suggestion? I spent my time composing a solution for exactly what you've asked for. If you don't want it - fine - but that doesn't mean it's a bad answer. In fact, it's exactly what you asked for. Mind removing the downvote?

Comment: @markrammmy Please review the code and let me know if you have any questions about it. Thank you for accepting my answer as your official answer. Were you the one who down-voted my answer to -1 or was that someone else? If that was you, could you just click the up arrow to remove it? Thanks. Hope the expanded explanation is what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use array_merge like so:
     `$result=mysqli_query($sql);
     $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     /*this returns 6 associative arrays $date, $time, $L1, $L2, $L3, $L4*/
     $time_data=array_merge($date,$time);
     $Ls_data=array_merge($L1, $L2, $L3, $L4);`